# Expectation Maximization (EM) stopping criterion

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, expectation-maximization, optimal-stopping

In several EM description (e.g., *Theory and Use of the EM Algorithm* By Maya R. Gupta and Yihua Chen) I read that two tipical stopping criterions for EM are defined on the difference between log-likelihood in two successive steps ($l(\theta^{(m+1)})-l(\theta^{(m)}) < \epsilon$) or between parameters ($\theta^{(m+1)}-\theta^{(m)} < \epsilon$). The two criteria seem to be equivalent because at a small variation on $\theta$ EM correspond a small variation on $l(\theta)$. However, I don't find a clear proof of this relation (if is true). Is there any reference or a proof that the differences on successive $l$ and successive $\theta$ are related?

Comment: Small changes in theta implying small changes in the log-likelihood is called continuity

Comment: Any proof of continuity?

Comment: But even if the likelihood is continuous, it may be very flat (or spiky). If, for instance, it is very flat --a common occurrence-- the criterion based on changes of the likelihood would lead you to stop much too early.

Comment: @F.Tusell true ^

Comment: @volperossa  A likelihood needs not be continuous, hence you cannot prove that in general. (Think of the likelihood of $\theta$ in a $U(0,\theta)$.)

Comment: @F.Tusell so the two stop criteria can not be considered the same?

Comment: @volperossa Right, they are not the same. It is true, though, that If the likelihood is continuous  different tolerances with each criterion would achieve similar results.

Comment: @F.Tusell is there a way to proof it formally?

Comment: Yes, just exploiting the idea @Taylor mentioned above that small changes in the parameters map to small changes in the likelihood when it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Even though likelihood function converges, the parameters may not converge, regardless of whether the likelihood is continuous or not!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).